# Error with popover and UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, popover, uialertcontroller

I have an app with a popover.  As I'm coming out of the popover.  I am dismissing the popover via a `UIAlertController` (user answers Yes).  Before dismissing the popover, though, I am calling a function on the delegate.  Within that function is another `UIAlertController`.  The second `UIAlertController` is not displaying because of the following error:

> Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior.

To demo this here, I created a quick project that shows the problem.  It is just a view controller with a button that calls the popover and a button on the popover that closes it and calls a delegate function containing another `UIAlertController`.

[image]

This is the code for the view controller that calls the popover:

```
//Delegate function called from popover
func doSomeStuff() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Some Stuff", message: "Do you want to do some stuff", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: {action in
        print("We did something here.")
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func callPopover(sender: UIButton) {
    let popoverVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PopoverView") as! PopoverController
    popoverVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    popoverVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200)

    if let popoverController = popoverVC.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverController.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)

        popoverController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds),0,0)
        popoverController.sourceView = callPopoverButton

        popoverController.delegate = self

        popoverVC.delegate = self

        self.presentViewController(popoverVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

//Allows popover to present on devices besides iPad.
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle{
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
}
```

The callPopover function is the action for the button on the first screen.

This is the code for the popover screen:

```
var delegate: ViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func returnToMainView(sender: UIButton) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Dismiss Popover", message: "Do you want to dismiss this popover?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: {action in
        self.delegate.doSomeStuff()
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When tapping the popover button on the first screen, the popover displays correctly:

[image]

Tapping the return button displays the alert:

[image]

Clicking Yes returns from the alert and should display the second alert, but that's where I get the error.

I think that the second alert is not displaying because the popover has not finished being dismissed, but have no idea how to get around it.

Comment: Sounds like exceptionally bad UX.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the you are presenting the second popup view controller from the first popup view controller which is being dismissed. That is causing the issue.

Instead why can't you present the second view controller from the navigation controller instead of first popup view controller.

Change this line of `presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)` to `self.navigartionController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)` in your`doSomeStuff()` method so that the first popup can dismiss freely and the navigation controller actually presents your second popup. Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't do anything different.  Still getting the error.  Still not getting the alert.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's possible to do an alert within an alert.  Makes sense, seeing as alert views are not modal.